# intersect of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I prove that if X and Y are n-dimensional subspaces of a vector space Z and X intersect Y is also dimension n, that X = Y?

It makes sense logically, but I'm not sure how I would prove it - going by properties of subspaces hasn't led me anywhere

Comment: An intersection of two sub spaces cannot have higher dimension than the original sub spaces (it should help if you think about it this way).

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that consists in remarking that :

$Y \cap X \subset Y$. 
Since both spaces have same dimension, we must have that $Y = Y \cap X$.
And by same argument with $X$ you obtain that $X = Y$.

Comment: Why does a subset of a space having the same dimension as that space mean that they are equal?

Comment: @Adam.V That’s really the essence of this question.  If they are not equal there exists a vector $x$ in the larger space that isn’t in the smaller subspace.  Take a basis for the latter and $x$ is not a linear combination of basis vectors, which lets you conclude that there are $n+1$ independent vectors in the larger space, contradicting the dimension.